# Programmatically updating redirect_uris in a Google app OAuth client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I created an app in the Google Cloud console with an OAuth 2.0 client.

Can I programmatically update the list of allowed redirect URIs to allow different subdomains? (a.example.com, b.example.com, etc.)

The only way I was able to do it was via the GUI at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials which is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this same thing.

All I could find was this, but it is only for Identity Aware Proxy
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iap/oauth-clients/create